# I have 8 shares of the Third National Bank and Trust Company of Scranton, PA - what is it worth?

Tags: stocks

I have 8 shares of the Third National Bank and Trust Company of Scranton, PA - what is it worth? Was taken over by Corestates which was taken over by Wachovia which was taken over by Wells Fargo

Comment: You'd have to research what the TNB-to-Corestates exchange was, and then the Corestates-to-Wachovia exchange, then Wachovia-to-WF.  It sure won't be easy.

Comment: It might be faster to ask Wells Fargo's [investor relations](https://www.wellsfargo.com/about/investor-relations/) or shareowner services.